# NginX still running when uninstalled it

Tags: nginx

I have tried to uninstall NGinX from my Ubuntu using following command:

```
 sudo apt-get remove nginx-core nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras nginx-common
```

I have used below command as well

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*
```

And still see below screen when I check NginX processes running.

What is happening??

[image: NginX still running after uninstalling it]

Comment: run `sudo pkill nginx`

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I have the same problem and this does not work as the process keeps spawning back.

Comment: @Newskooler, that would mean that some other process manager is taking care of spawning it back. See if there is something else controlling nginx

Answer (score 9):

Try to run `sudo killall nginx`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear the web browser cache. It works for me.

Comment: God bless you xx

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once as well.

To fix this you will want to disable the systemd boot process from starting.

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```

That way on next reboot it shouldn't start again.